# Using TensorFlow through Jupyter (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter

*Apologies in advance, I think the issue is quite perplexing!*

**I would like to use TensorFlow through Jupyter, with a Python3 kernel.**

However the command `import tensorflow as tf` returns the error: `ImportError: No module named tensorflow` when either Python2 or Python3 is specified as the Jupyter kernel.

- I have Python 2 and Python 3 installed on my Mac and can access both
  versions through Terminal.
- I installed [TensorFlow for Python 3](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#download-and-setup), however I can only access it via Python 2 on the Terminal.

As such, this question is really two-fold:

1. I want to get TensorFlow working with Python3
2. ...which should lead to TensorFlow working with Jupyter on the Python3 terminal.

Comment: did you install tensorflow? are you able to run `import tensorflow` from a python interpreter ?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and solved it using the tutorial [Using a virtualenv in an IPython notebook](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs). I'll walk you through the steps I took.

I am using Anaconda, and I installed a new environment `tensorflow` using [these instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation) at `tensorflow.org`. After that, here is how I got `tensorflow` to work in a Jupyter notebook:

1. Open Terminal
2. Run `source activate tensorflow`. You should now see `(tensorflow)` at the beginning of the prompt.
3. Now that we are in the `tensorflow` environment, we want to install `ipython` and `jupyter` in this environment: Run

   ```
   conda install ipython
   ```

   and

   ```
   conda install jupyter
   ```
4. Now follow the instructions in the tutorial linked above. I'll repeat them here with a bit more information added. First run

   ```
   ipython kernelspec install-self --user
   ```

   The result for me was `Installed kernelspec python3 in /Users/charliebrummitt/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3`
5. Run the following:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.ipython/kernels
   ```

   Then run the following with `<kernel_name>` replaced by a name of your choice (I chose `tfkernel`) and replace the first path (i.e., `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/pythonX`) by the path generated in step 4:

   ```
   mv ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/pythonX ~/.ipython/kernels/<kernel_name>
   ```
6. Now you'll see a new kernel if you open a Jupyter notebook and select `Kernel -> Change kernel` from the menu. But the new kernel will have the same name as your previous kernel (for me it was called `Python 3`). To give your new kernel a unique name, run in Terminal

   ```
   cd ~/.ipython/kernels/tfkernel/
   ```

   and then run `vim kernel.json` to edit the file `kernel.json` so that you replace the value of `"display_name"` from the default (`Python 3`) to a new name (I chose to call it `"tfkernel"`). Save and exit `vim` by typing `:wq` while in command mode.
7. Open a new Jupyter notebook and type `import tensorflow as tf`. If you didn't get `ImportError` then you are ready to go!

Comment: this would be quite useful if translated to "windows" language.  Many corporations in industry use/require the 2nd most recent Microsoft operating system.

Comment: Such a lifesaver..I was able to import tensorflow when running in RHEL without "conda install jupyter/ipython" once I source avtivated tensorflow. As I moved into AWS Linuximage, it required me to do this step. Thanks for sharing. I did not do the "ipython kernelspec install-self --user" but I will keep it to have all binaries loaded up

Comment: Thanks, but followed all your instructions on Mac El Capitan (many times!) and still `ImportError` exception is thrown. It's importing `tf` in the python's CLI, but no luck in the Notebooks!! Was trying for the last 3 hours, maybe it's time to give up..

Comment: I do not have a ~/.local/share/jupyter folder, but I was able to follow all of the steps until 5. the ipython kernelspec was installed in /Users/amc/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python2... what should I do?