# Windows: Using Tensorflow with Python 3 instead of Python 2 (Docker)

Tags: python, windows, docker, kernel, tensorflow

My problem is very similar to the one stated here:
[Using TensorFlow through Jupyter (Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771285/using-tensorflow-through-jupyter-python-3)

So, I have both installed Python 2 and Python 3 (3.4.3). Currently Tensorflow runs only with Python 2 but I would prefer using a Python 3 kernel.
The difference to the thread: I have a Windows System and use Docker to get TensorFlow running.

If I open regular Jupyter Notebooks (not using TF) I use Python 3 by default. I also may change the kernels (and their names) by the way described in the abovementioned thread, however this does not affect the Python-2-Kernel for TF, since it seemed to be stored in another directory. In the TF-environment the only kernel I can access is this Python 2 kernel. 
Unfortunately, I cannot even find out that directory and even not where my Notebooks created with TF are stored; it all seems to be hidden by Docker.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone created a Tensorflow + Jupyter + Python 3 Docker image (`erroneousboat/tensorflow-python3-jupyter`) that should fit your needs.

You should be able to run the image and sync the Jupyter notebook files to your Windows filesystem with the following, replacing `[PATH_TO_NOTEBOOKS_ON_LOCAL_COMPUTER]` with whatever folder on your local computer you want the Jupyter notebooks sync'd to.

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v [PATH_TO_NOTEBOOKS_ON_LOCAL_COMPUTER]:/notebooks -it erroneousboat/tensorflow-python3-jupyter
```

Comment: Wow, that was incredibly helpful and did it in the end, thanks a lot!!
Stupid me, I can still not access the files I wrote using Tensorflow via regular navigation through windows folders. 
How can I find out WHERE these files are actually saved? They're definitely not in the folder I defined as local path

Comment: Glad that helped! To find where the files were actually saved, I'd recommend you check out this documentation from Docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/. 

Specifically, I would check out the section that starts:

On Windows, mount directories using:

`docker run -v /c/Users/<path>:/<container path> ...`

Comment: Sorry for reviving this thread: 
Tensorflow runs now succesfully with python 3.4, but still gives me weird errors from time to time, which I don't get by executing the same code in my ubuntu shell (I have 2 totally distinct tensorflow environments, one using docker, one within the ubuntu shell of Windows 10):

`__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments:
-f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-2d578231-a0db-4c19-9761-36b18749e0fd.json

An expcetion has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback`

Do you have any idea what might be wrong with my kernel here?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in macOS, I installed both python2 and python3 in my tensorflow docker container.

First update container's system in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then install pip3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Check whether pip3 is installed:

```
python3 -m pip -V
```

Update pip3:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Finally you can install IPython kernel as guided in the [doc](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html):

```
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```