# Tensorflow importing error in Jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

So I managed **all other packages** (such as cv2, pandas, matplotlib..) **work well** in the **default kernel** **or Python 3 kernel**, **except Tensorflow.**

- Tensorflow does not import with Kernel: "Python 3" or "Python default".

import tensorflow as tf

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-41389fad42b5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

When I choose "env: tensorflow" kernel, my other packages such as pandas, cv2 all collapse. Thus, I try to use "default" kernel or "Python 3" kernel.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you `import tensorflow` from a `python3` interactive session? You may just need to `pip3 install` the [TensorFlow python3 package](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't loaded the tensorflow kernel, please follow instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771285/using-tensorflow-through-jupyter-python-3).

Comment: thanks. The problem is that when I choose "env: tensorflow" kernel, my other packages such as pandas, cv2 all collapse  (-- I can solve these problems one by one but too painful. I would rather solve one problem, Tensorflow in my kernel "Python 3")  -- Please point out if I misunderstand your point and the link.